# Convert Tensorflow BatchDataset to Numpy Array with Images and Labels

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a directory of images and am taking them in like this:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=Val_Split,
    subset='training',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
```

I then after building the model, I run `tuner.search(train_ds, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])` using the BatchDataset and it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DecisionTree/Gender/main.py", line 133, in <module>
    tuner.search(train_ds, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/base_tuner.py", line 131, in search
    self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/tuners/hyperband.py", line 354, in run_trial
    super(Hyperband, self).run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/multi_execution_tuner.py", line 96, in run_trial
    history = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, fit_args, copied_fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/tuner.py", line 141, in _build_and_fit_model
    return model.fit(*fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1041, in fit
    (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1359, in train_validation_split
    "arrays, found following types in the input: {}".format(unsplitable))
ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>]
```

I tried many methods to convert this to a Numpy array by using the `.take()`, `iter()`, and `next()` with no success. How can I get this to work?

Here is my entire code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import kerastuner as kt
import os
import pathlib
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
import datetime
import glob
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops import AUTOTUNE

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Create 2 virtual GPUs with 1GB memory each
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024),
         tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPU,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)

AUTOTUNE=AUTOTUNE

epochs = 500
steps_per_epoch = 10
batch_size = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 180
IMG_WIDTH = 180

train_dir = "Training"
pred_dir = "Pred"

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

pred_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

Val_Split = 0.2

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=Val_Split,
    subset='training',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=Val_Split,
    subset='validation',
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

def model_builder(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
       
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(20, activation="relu"))
    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=0, max_value=512, step=32)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                  loss="binary_crossentropy",
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
                  
    return model
    
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='my_dir',
                     project_name='intro_to_kt')

stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)



tuner.search(test_ds, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])

best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

print(f"""
The hyperparameter search is complete. The optimal number of units in the first densely-connected
layer is {best_hps.get('units')} and the optimal learning rate for the optimizer
is {best_hps.get('learning_rate')}.
""")


model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

model.summary()
#tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB')
checkpoint_path = "training_gender/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

history = model.fit(train_ds,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,validation_data=test_data_gen,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[cp_callback, tensorboard_callback])

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
print('Best epoch: %d' % (best_epoch,))


hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# Retrain the model
hypermodel.fit(train_ds, epochs=best_epoch, validation_split=0.2)


hypermodel.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
hypermodel.save('gender.h5', include_optimizer=True)

test_loss, test_acc = hypermodel.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc*100, "%")

print(hypermodel.predict(test_ds))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to convert an image dataset into X and Y NumPy arrays are as follows:

NOTE: This code is borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/PARASTOOP/331874a46a3098dbd15ebb2863d11518). This code is written by "PARASTOOP" on Github.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Settings:
img_size = 64
grayscale_images = False
num_class = 2
test_size = 0.2


def get_img(data_path):
    # Getting image array from path:
    img = imread(data_path, flatten=grayscale_images)
    img = imresize(img, (img_size, img_size, 3)) #1 if grayscale_images else 3
    return img

def get_dataset(dataset_path='data/train'):
    # Getting all data from data path:
    try:
        X = np.load('npy_dataset/X.npy')
        Y = np.load('npy_dataset/Y.npy')
    except:
        labels = listdir(dataset_path) # Geting labels
        X = []
        Y = []
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            datas_path = dataset_path+'/'+label
            for data in listdir(datas_path):
                img = get_img(datas_path+'/'+data)
                X.append(img)
                Y.append(i)
        # Create dateset:
        X = 1-np.array(X).astype('float32')/255.
        Y = np.array(Y).astype('float32')
        Y = to_categorical(Y, num_class)
        if not os.path.exists('npy_dataset/'):
            os.makedirs('npy_dataset/')
        np.save('npy_dataset/X.npy', X)
        np.save('npy_dataset/Y.npy', Y)
    X, X_test, Y, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
    return X, X_test, Y, Y_test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_dataset()
```

With this code, you can convert your image dataset into X and Y .npy dataset and the you can load it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load entire dataset
X = np.load('X.npy')
Y = np.load('Y.npy')


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(X[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

NOTE: This code also crashes if your dataset is too big because it fills up your RAM.
NOTE: This code also for some reason alters your images to be blue-tinted when viewed using Matplotlib so if anyone knows the solution, please comment below.

Comment: The reason matplotlib shows the image blue tinted is that the image follows BGR order. You need to convert the image from BGR to RGB.